# The plane and hyperplane concepts in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I am going slowly through this book "Vector Calculus"
by Peter Baxandall (Author), Hans Liebeck (Author).

[https://www.amazon.com/Vector-Calculus-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486466205](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486466205)

On page 69-70 there's this definition (see below), and I am confused about point [iv] from it.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

The book does have provide a prior definition of what a **plane** means in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I thought a **plane** in $\mathbb{R}^n$ always means a **hyperplane** i.e. an object of $n-1$ dimensions determined by a point $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and by $(n-1)$ linearly independent vectors (e.g. $(n-1)$ pairwise orthogonal non-zero vectors). So the hyperplane is the set of all points $B$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\overrightarrow{AB}\ $ is a linear combination of the given $n-1$ vectors. Is my understanding of a **hyperplane** correct?

But it seems here they use the term **plane** in the sense of an object of 2 dimensions determined by a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the point $A = h(s)$) and by two linearly independent vectors $T(s), N(s)$. Is that the right way to understand item [iv]? I mean, is it the set of all points $B$ such that the $\overrightarrow{AB}\ $ is a linear combination of $T(s), N(s)$?

Also, is my understanding/definition of a **hyperplane** correct?

Sorry about the math pictures, I am not sure I can type all this in MathJax.

Note that Fig.2.17 (i) doesn't help to clear my confusion because in that case $n=3$ i.e. $n-1 = 2$ so there's no difference between a hyperplane and a plane (at least in the way which I currently understand them).

Comment: In the affine space $\Bbb R^n$, a **plane** is always a subspace of dimension 2, while a **hyperplane** is always a subspace of dimension $n-1$ (of codimension $1$, actually). Therefore a plane is a hyperplane in $\Bbb R^3$, and a line is a hyperplane in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut So my understanding above is correct, right? My confusion came from the fact that every time I google "plane in n-dimensional space", I get pages about hyperplane. So I thought there's no such thing as plane (2-dimensional) in an n-dimensional space.

Comment: Since there are two contradictory statements in the question (planes are hyperplanes / planes are of dimension 2), I couldn't just say "you are correct". One of your statements is correct, yes.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Well, I meant that I thought a plane is always a hyperplane but then I realized that if that is so then [iv] would make no sense. So I realized that by plane the authors mean a 2-dimensional object here in this definition. So based on your note I think this is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.